# Uploading by firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I tried to uplad (multi photos) using **firebase storage** (site) and it upladed successfully but I can NOT find it in **database section** anywhere and also it do not appear in application.

How can I upload **multi photos** by firebase site and appear on database section and also my application?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firebase storage and realtime database are two different entities, so after uploading image to firebase storage you need to save the download url in realtime database on your own, at path of your choice, in the following example, images url are being  saved at **images** path

```
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/rivers.jpg').put(file);
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
  var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
}, function(error) {
  // error uploading file
}, function() {
  // File uploaded successfully, now store the download url in realtime database
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    firebase.database().ref('images').set({
       image:downloadURL
    });
  });
});
```

before saving images url in realtime database make sure you have enabled realtime database for [your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)

Comment: thank you @ked
I thought it's connected with Visual Stodio code in HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can't save photos directly in the realtime-database. After you upload the photos get the **URL**s and save them in the realtime-database.

Comment: How I can do that ?

Comment: @HannayGamal what programming language you use https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage

Comment: my application in java, my Visual Studio in HTML cz I think it's connected with VS too. Thank you